# Third order ODE in R (numerical vs analytical solutions)

Tags: r, ode

y'''(t)-3*y'(t)-2*y(t)=-12*e^(-t) , with initial conditions y'(0)=1, y''(0)=8, y(0) =0.

Did the analytical solution by hand and ploted it in R (below) and i am now trying to compare it with the numerical solution.

```
# Analytic solution #
O3<-function(t) (2*t^2*exp(-t)+(2/3)*exp(2*t)-(2/3)*exp(-t)-t*exp(-t))
curve(O3,0,5,lty=1,add=T,col="green")
```

Did the Numeric numerical solution in R but the charts don´t match. Any thoughts of which one can be wrong or maybe bot even?

```
# Define the ODE system
ode_system <- function(t, y, parms) {
 y1 <- y[1]  # y(t)
 y2 <- y[2]  # y'(t)
 y3 <- y[3]  # y''(t)

dy1dt <- y2
dy2dt <- y3
dy3dt <- 3 * y2 + 2 * y1 + 12 * exp(-t)

 return(list(c(dy1dt, dy2dt, dy3dt)))
}

# Set initial conditions
initial_conditions <- c(y1 = 0, y2 = 1, y3 = 8)

# Set time points for the solution
times <- seq(0, 5, by =0.001)  # Adjust the range and step size as needed

# Solve the ODE
solution <- ode(y = initial_conditions, times = times, func = ode_system, parms = NULL)

# Extract the results
result_df <- as.data.frame(solution)

# Plot the solution
plot(result_df$time, result_df$y1, type = 'l', col = 'blue', xlab = 'Time', ylab = 'y(t)',
 main = 'Numerical Solution of the ODE')

# Add labels and legend
   legend("topright", legend = c("y(t)"), col = c("blue"), lty = 1)
```

Comment: The forcing term, aka the original right side, switched its sign?

Comment: @lutz-lehmann, Many thanks! That was it. Appreciated.